# How reference value types in Javascript works?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm learning Javascript, based on my knowledge that the reference type like object below is created in the heap, and point to a new piece of memory in the stack. But what happened when I've tried to declare an object like this:

`let object = { id: 1223, title: 'test' };`

and when I reassigned it:

`object = { newId: object.id, newTitle: object.title };`

I got:

`object = { newId: 1223, newTitle: 'test' };`

I'm so curious as to why this is possible, Has the property name gone when I reassigned the object? and How it works behind the screen?

Please give me some explanations, keywords, or documents.

Many thanks.

P/s. Something I forgot is that the `=` operator's associativity happened from right to left, so the object at this point was not mutated until the execution met the `=`. Maybe it is the answer for my question somehow.

Comment: What don't you understand? You created a new object, and referred to the old object when you were creating it.

Comment: What were you expecting instead of the result you got?

Comment: The variable `object` isn't reassigned until after the expression with the value is evaluated. That's why you can refer to the old object's properties.

Comment: "reassign object in JS is not desirable" -- you're not reassigning an object, you're reassigning a variable. This happens all the time, there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: That's just because you didn't assigned new values to new object and you refered to defined values at first line beginning with `let`

Comment: "is created in the heap, and point to a new piece of memory in the stack" this sounds kind of backwards.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know how it work behind the scence. Your 3rd comment seemed to be reasonable. Could you give me some document ?

Comment: I don't know any documents on how it works behind the scenes. But if you know about C structs and pointers, it's similar to that.

Comment: @ASDFGerte that what I've got from a JavaScript senior, Is something wrong ?

Comment: @Barmar JS was my first language to know, anyway, thank you.

Comment: `variable = { ... }` simply creates the object on the heap, then assigns the heap location to the variable's value. There's nothing complicated about it.

Comment: @Phucq.ins It might be due to lack of markup, but the object is never mutated (no properties are being changed), the *variable* `object` is reassiged/overwritten. Notice that your code does create two separate objects.

Comment: The only “document” I can think of which explains what’s going on behind the scene is the [ECMAScript specification](//tc39.es/ecma262). If you want to know how browsers implement this, you’ll have to look for the source code of various browser engines.